# unable to click or sendkeys on webElements in Protractor Cucumber Framework

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

My Code is working fine with out any failure but without performing any click or sendkeys or any other actions.. browser is closing automatically and it is not even responding for browser.sleep command..when using console.log it is printing text but element action is not working

### StepDef file

```
var page=require("..\\src\\StepDefFiles\\testpage.js");
var test=function(){
     Given('Load the URL', function () {
        page.browserInit();
       });
     
       Given('Get the Title', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
          browser.getTitle().then(function(title){
              console.log(title);
          })
         });
       
       Then('Login in to the account', function () {
             page.gmailLink();
         
         });
       

       Then('validate the home page', function () {
          browser.getTitle().then(function(Title){
              if(Title.indexOf("sign in")!=-1){
                  console.log(Title);
              }
          })
       });
}
module.exports=new test();
```

### Test Page File

```
var testPage=function(){
    
    this.browserInit=function(){
         browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
         browser.get("https://google.com");
         browser.sleep(5000);
         browser.manage().window().maximize();
         browser.sleep(5000);
    }
    
    this.gmailLink=function(){
        element(By.xpath("//a[text()='Gmail']")).click();
    }
    
}
module.exports=new testPage();
```

### Config File

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
getPageTimeout: 60000,
allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
framework: 'custom',
// path relative to the current config file
frameworkPath: require.resolve('C:\\Users\\DELL\\node_modules\\protractor-cucumber-framework'),
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},

// Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
specs: [
    '..\\Protractor_Cucumber\\src\\FeatureFiles\\Test.feature'
],

cucumberOpts: {
    require: '..\\Protractor_Cucumber\\src\\StepDefFiles\\stepDef.js',
    tags: false,
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
},
 onPrepare: function () {
const {Given, Then, When, Before} = require('C:\\Users\\DELL\\node_modules\\cucumber');
global.Given = Given;
global.When = When;
global.Then = Then;
global.Before = Before;
  }
};
```

### Feature file

```
Feature: Title of your feature
  I want to use this template for my feature file

  Scenario: Title of your scenario
    Given Load the URL
    And   Get the Title
    Then  Login in to the account
    And   validate the home page
```

### Console log

```
21:41:37] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:41:37] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
.....

1 scenario (1 passed)
4 steps (4 passed)
0m00.030s
Google
[21:41:46] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[21:41:46] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

it would be a great help for me if anybody able to answer this one

Comment: which console logs get printed?

Comment: Executed console log

Comment: What's the version of your protractor, protractor-cucumber-framework, and cucumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No need to wrap step function into another function and export, detail at [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/6023f98436482f2640a623ef78a243b7aa2dd7a9/features/step_definitions/file_steps.js)
2. You need to return a promise for each step function, detail at [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/6023f98436482f2640a623ef78a243b7aa2dd7a9/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md)

Change your StepDef file as following:

```
var page = require("../src/StepDefFiles/testpage.js");

Given('Load the URL', function() {
  return page.browserInit();
});

Given('Get the Title', function() {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log(title);
  })
});

Then('Login in to the account', function() {
  return page.gmailLink();
});

Then('validate the home page', function() {
  return browser.getTitle().then(function(Title) {
    if (Title.indexOf("sign in") != -1) {
      console.log(Title);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: This solution not worked for me... When I removed  the exports. Config line.. It is unable to find the stepdef file and return for every method also not worked for me